# ROI of palmprint

Tags: matlab

I'm doing project on personal verification using palmprint biometrics. I want to extract a Region of Interest (ROI) of palmprints in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

In the image processing toolbox in matlab there are many ways to manually extract a region of interest. Personally, I often use "roipoly". 
(http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/roipoly.html)

Just type

```
m = roipoly(I);
```

where I is your image.

Answer (score 0):

**Auto ROI Extraction**
Locating the ROI of Palmprint images is a popular problem in biometrics and image processing. This is the primary step in developing a biometric system based on palmprint image recognition. 
There are a lot of methods presented already. 
This is one method I used.

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46573-roi-of-palmprint-images